# Highlighting a div element within another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to alter the background color of a child element.

This is attempted with the code:

```
arrdiv[i].highlight.style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

Where highlight is the name of the div i'm attempting to alter.
This is obviously incorrect, but hopefully it demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

Here is the function:

```
function mainFormHideShow(id, highlight_id, arrDiv) 
{ 
    var idNum = id*1;
    var l = arrDiv.length;
    var i = idNum%l;
    var highlight = 'highlight' + highlight_id;

    for (var j=0; j<l; j++)
    {
        $(arrDiv[j]).hide();
    }

    arrDiv[i].style.display = "block";

    arrdiv[i].highlight.style.backgroundColor = "black";

}
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged jQuery?

Comment: He does seem to use some jQuery - but he's mixing it with plain DOM accesses.

Comment: Could you supply HTML as well just so we know there are no silly syntax errors.

Comment: `var idNum = id*1; ... var i = idNum%l; // what?`

Comment: arrDiv[i].style.display = "block";   
arrdiv[i].highlight.style.backgroundColor = "black";  shouldn't these 2 statements inside the for loop?

Comment: Anyway, I admit I don't get it at all. If you have the name, why don't just use `$('[name="' + someName + '"]').css('backgroundColor', 'black')`? What's the point of using some strange manipulations here?

Comment: @raina77ow - yeah, `var idNum = id*1;` is atleast a way to force an number versus string.  However, `any number % 1` will always be `0`...

Comment: @kmfk It's not 1, it's 'el' there. My point is `someString % number` is actually `Number(someString) % number`.

Comment: @raina77ow - ah, yeah misread the `L`

Comment: @kmfk Thanks for the quick response guys.  Don't mind my wacky variables...they work.  I'm block-displaying the one div and hiding the rest.  The problem is that within the displayed div, I want to alter the background-color of a child div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `id` property rather than `name` property. So, you can do this:

```
document.getElementById('highlight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

If you want to use `name` property anyway, you have to do something like this:

```
var myDivs = document.getElementsByName('highlight');
myDivs[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
```

If you're using jQuery:

```
$("#highlight").css("backgroundColor", "black");
```

Or:

```
$("[name=highlight]").css("backgroundColor", "black");
```